# How to parse dictionary structure data with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have html file as follows:

```
<div>
                Person 1<br/>
                2008<br/>
</div>
<div style="font-weight: bold;">
                Professional Athlete<br/>
</div>
<b>Status:</b>
            Married
            <br/>
<b>Gender:</b>
            Male
            <br/>
<b>First Name: </b>
            Tom
            <br/>
<b>Last Name: </b>
            Cruiz
            <br/>
<br/>
<hr/>
<div style="clear: both">
</div>
<div>
                Person 2<br/>
                2008<br/>
</div>
<div style="font-weight: bold;">
                Another Person<br/>
</div>
<b>Status:</b>
            Single
            <br/>
<b>Gender:</b>
            Female
            <br/>
<b>First Name: </b>
            Sarah
            <br/>
<b>Middle Name: </b>
            M
            <br/>
<b>Last Name: </b>
            Jones
            <br/>
<br/>
<hr/>
<div style="clear: both">
</div>
```

Notice that each group of entry (a person) is separated by

```
<hr/>
<div style="clear: both">
</div>
```

Some of the information has a  tag, but some are outside of the tag like "**Last Name:** Jones". Also, not all entries has all the information, for example, the first entry doesn't have "middle name". How do I parse it with BeautifulSoup and put them into a pandas table?

I can do something like

```
s1status = soup.find(string='Status:')
s1status.next_element.strip()
```

but how can I keep all the entry matched up?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to find_all('string in tag') then do .next_sibling.strip() but can't figure out how to keep each entry as a group. I'm quite new in parsing.

Comment: something like s1status = s1.find(string='Status:')
s1status.next_element.strip()

Comment: @l'L'l I thought this is a place to ask questions? I'm sorry my skill isn't up to bar, but wby so patronizing?

Comment: @pynoob, Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It's best to have something to show you've made an effort to solve the issue yourself before just asking others to do it for you. good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for `<b>` elements that contains `'First Name:'`, `'Middle Name:'` or `'Last Name:'` and then search for next text sibling. For example (`txt` is your HTML snippet from the question):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

names = []
for b in soup.find_all('b', text=lambda t: t.strip() in ('First Name:', 'Middle Name:', 'Last Name:')):
    if b.text.strip() == 'First Name:':
        names.append([])
    names[-1].append(b.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip())

print(names)
```

Prints:

```
[['Tom', 'Cruiz'], ['Sarah', 'M', 'Jones']]
```